# Which physical address to use?

Tags: local-seo, address, google-my-business

My business postal code had recently changed from k6h5r5 to K6h7r7. I went and updated Google My Business and all the places where my business is listed.

However, I realized that Google keeps the old one (k6h5r5). I tried many times to change it there but without success.

Keeping in mind that this change is not affecting the mail delivery, should I go and change everything back to k6h5r5?

[image: Screenshot from Google Search, showing the old code] [image: Screenshot from Google business info, showing the old code]

Comment: Just to clarify, is the address exactly the same but only the postal code changed?
How does your address come up on Google maps? Is the flag marker in the right spot with the old or new postal code?

Comment: "...change everything back to k6h5r5?" - Has the postal code changed or not?! If Google's records are out of date, it doesn't mean they are correct. (??)

Comment: You can see that even from google search and google my business there is a difference (road and Rd). It makes me confused on what to rely on. See the attached pictures .

Comment: Road, rd, St, Street is not that relevant since the most of your citations from various leading business directories will use a variation, its near impossible to get them all to match, so even if Google considers it Rd, and not Road... then chances are your going to have various sites that use one or the other. I'm sure they are smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

*Two things come to mind:*

1. It's rather common that when updating the business name or moving address it will prompt for the business to be verified once more through their postcard service. Ensure that your business has not selected to be verified again since any changes will not be published until that process is complete, Google will continue to display the old address until you have provided them passcode that they send you.
2. It's rather common when updating the business name or moving address that it will be prompt for a manual review by one of Google's team, during this time, the new address or business name will not be displayed until it is approved.

You will need to login to [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/) to confirm whether or not the business is awaiting approval via a reviewer editor or by postcode verification.

> [SOURCE](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7005371)
>
> If your business moves, update your address in Google My Business so
>   customers can visit your new location. Don’t create a new business
>   listing if you’ve moved from one location to another. You **may be asked**
>   **to verify** your new business address once you update it.

Answer (score 0):

It's vital you keep the Name, Address, Phone Number, and URL consistent across all your listings. Have you tried verifying the new address on Google Maps yet? I recommend you check out https://moz.com/blog/moz-local-uk. We utilize their service for all our clients and get great results. The price is quite affordable so it might be a good solution for you to consider.